LDAPS issue between openbsd and Ubuntu
I am having issues with LDAP.  I have an overarching VM openbsd that has the LDAP database that all other VM's access based on certificating.  SO far, it has been conveniently set up so that all I have to do is scp a cacert.pem file into the file, configure whatever ldap.conf file is in the destination  VM after installing the necessary utilities, and I should be connected to the database and be able to use the ldap accounts from my VM effortlessly.  However whenever I try and use the VM to id placeholder that should simply work from nssconfig, something like id username of ldap account does not work.  Whenever I look into the authentification logs, they just say:
ubuntu sudo: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
ubuntu sudo: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://servername: Protocol error
I have done all the tests to make sure everything else works, and they do.
openssl s_client -connect
This test worked and I was able to connect
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=placeholder,dc=placeholder" "(uid=placeholder)"
The above also worked, so I know my LDAP root account works, that I can connect to the LDAP database, and that the account I am trying to id exists, so the issue has to be in ubuntu, but I don't know how to fix it.
The only thing I can think of is off the nsswitch.conf, which I didn't change much just:
passwd:         files systemd ldap
group:          files systemd ldap
shadow:         files systemd ldap
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis



You've tagged your Ubuntu release as being the 2014-April (14.04) release; is that correct?

Only fully supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Yes, it is tagged correctly
